# CSS nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website that includes 3 sections with the class `.card` and I am trying to use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors to style the backgrounds of the 1st and 3rd `.card` sections white color and the 2nd section purple gradient but the selectors aren't working as I want them to. I want them to be like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIRqb.jpg), but it's appearing as shown in the fiddle. Maybe I am not understanding the odd and even selectors correctly.

```css
:root {
  --gradient: linear-gradient(hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
  --accent-grey-100: hsl(240°, 78%, 98%);
  --accent-grey-300: hsl(234°, 14%, 74%);
  --accent-grey-600: hsl(233°, 13%, 49%);
  --accent-grey-900: hsl(232°, 13%, 33%);
  --neutral: #fff;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: #F6F6FE url("../images/bg-top.svg") no-repeat fixed right top;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  padding: 4em;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--neutral);
}

.card:nth-child(even) {
  background: var(--gradient);
}

.card>div+div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Pricing component with toggle</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <section class="header">
      <h1>Our Pricing</h1>
      <div class="toggle">
        Annually Monthly
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="card" id="basic">
      <div>
        <h3>Basic</h3>

        <h2>&dollar;19.99</h2>
        <h2>&dollar;199.99</h2>
      </div>

      <div>500 GB Storage</div>

      <div>2 Users Allowed</div>

      <div>Send up to 3 GB</div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="button button-main">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="card" id="professional">
      <div>
        <h3>Professional</h3>

        <h2>&dollar;24.99</h2>
        <h2>&dollar;249.99</h2>
      </div>

      <div>1 TB Storage</div>

      <div>5 Users Allowed</div>

      <div>Send up to 10 GB</div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="button button-inverse">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="card" id="master">
      <div>
        <h3>Master</h3>

        <h2>&dollar;39.99</h2>
        <h2>&dollar;399.99</h2>
      </div>

      <div>2 TB Storage</div>

      <div>10 Users Allowed</div>

      <div>Send up to 20 GB</div>

      <div>
        <a href="" class="button button-main">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="#">Sachin Jadhav</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. `:nth-child` only selects elements that are the **n-th child** of their parents, regardless of any further constraints your selector may have. Only after picking those elements, the browsers filters the matching result and removes all elements from it that don't match `.card`. There is no `nth-of-class` in CSS.

Comment: Change your :nth-child with numeric instead of odd/even                                                   .card:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: var(--neutral);
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  background: var(--gradient);
}

Comment: @connexo what happens if I change the selector to `.container > .card:nth-child(odd)`, would that work as `:nth-child` selects the children of the parent? Did you mean the nth-child selectors only selects HTML elements like section, div, etc, and not classes?

Comment: Read my comment again: *[...] regardless of any further constraints your selector may have.*

Comment: Ya I understood that, when you say "nth-child only selects elements that are the n-th child of their parents" you mean that `:nth-child` only works on HTML tags like div, section, ul, etc which are children of a parent element?